# ASP.NET appsettings.json does not exist in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

I am following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) on how to create a Web API with ASP.NET Core and MongoDB. I have followed every step successfully up until the [Add a configuration model section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-configuration-model). In the guide, I need to locate `appsettings.json` and add database configuration values to my project. The problem is that the file they mention `appsettings.json` does not exist in my project.

In the guide, its implied that the file should already exist and should even already have content in it, so I don't know if I should just create it.

I have looked online and all over my project but nothing seems to be definitive on what is the right thing to do (some guides contradict each other, etc.).

Apart from the default ones, I explicitly installed have the following NuGet packages:

- `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` (I thought this might help, but it didn't)
- `MongoDB.Driver` (the instructions on the guide said to)

My setup is the following:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.6
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03752
- ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019 16.4.462.24200
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019 16.4.462.24200

I have closed and re-opened VS but that didn't change anything.

This is my solution explorer:

[image]

Should I just create the file? In the guide, it already has content in it. What about that?

Is there a new/different way of add database configuration values to my project?

Is the guide outdated? If it is completely unusable, can you point me to a newer guide on how to Create a web API with ASP.NET Core and MongoDB?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you created a .NET Framework project. The tutorial you referenced is using .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app exists for ASP.NET core projects. You mistakenly created, I believe, an ASP.NET framewok project. The tutorial is about the ASP.NET core.